# Code to trade inverse EFT's - Two Symbols Same Charts - Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script, inverse-relationship

thanks in advance for your help.

I have a strategy to trade inverse ETF's, as opposed to trading long and then short.  I am trying to figure out the code in Pine 5 to tell the script / strategy when a short signal is issued to buy a certain symbol.  In my case, long is TNA and short is TZA (its inverse).  In the reference manual it has a symbol refence, see [Pine Reference manual for Symbol](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dsymbol) That code is: `input.symbol

input.symbol(defval, title, tooltip, inline, group, confirm) → input string
EXAMPLE
i_sym = input.symbol("DELL", "Symbol")
s = request.security(i_sym, 'D', close)
plot(s)`enter code here`

RETURNS
Value of input variable.`

That said, will a strategy recognize this?  Is there a better/proper way to do this?

Comment: How do you execute the strategy? How do you open a position on the exchange? (when you do that I assume you need to provide a symbol)

Comment: I was mistake taht TV could auto trade, alas it cannot.  That said, there should be a way to code algo trade inverse ETF's.